# Avoiding extra lines in Ruby JSON.pretty_generate

Tags: json, ruby

I would like to produce JSON formatted like this:

```
{
   "a": {
       "b": 1
   },
   "c": [
       2
   ],
   "d": [],
   "e": {}
}
```

This is easy to do with the standard JSON support in Python, JavaScript, and Go.

In Ruby, I'm having trouble getting that exact output:

```
$ ~/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/bin/irb 
irb(main):001:0> require 'json'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> puts JSON.pretty_generate({"a" => {"b" => 1}, "c" => [2], "d" => [], "e" => {}})
{
  "a": {
    "b": 1
  },
  "c": [
    2
  ],
  "d": [

  ],
  "e": {
  }
}
=> nil
```

The problems:

- Empty objects are rendered on two lines.
- Empty arrays are rendered on three(!) lines.

Is there a simple way to get the Ruby standard JSON support to render the output I want?

Answer (score 3):

✅ I found the **[neatjson](https://github.com/Phrogz/NeatJSON#readme)** gem useful to generate JSON where **empty arrays/hashes** are rendered **on a single line** instead of 3.

You can use [this online visual tool](http://phrogz.net/JS/NeatJSON/) to **find** the ad-hoc **[options](https://github.com/Phrogz/NeatJSON#options)**.

You can **install it** using either `gem install neatjson` or append `gem 'neatjson', '0.9'` to your `Gemfile`(`0.9` was the most recent version at the time of this writing, feel free to adjust).

Then here is how to **use it** to get the expected output:

```rb
require 'json'
require 'neatjson'

structure = {
  "a" => {"b" => 1},
  "c" => [2],
  "d" => [],
  "e" => {}, 
  "f" => "string with [     ] and {       }"
}

json = JSON.neat_generate(
  structure,
  { 
    wrap:        true,
    indent:      '    ',
    after_colon: 1,
    after_comma: 1
  }
)
puts "#{json}\n"
```

I hope this helps, I did not find a way to configure `JSON.pretty_generate` do this and `neatjson` can fix this issue. It offers a myriad of options  to fine tune the JSON string.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible using Ruby's standard library JSON.
`JSON.pretty_generate` uses [JSON.generate](https://apidock.com/ruby/JSON/generate) with a pre-defined configuration:

```
JSON::PRETTY_STATE_PROTOTYPE.to_hash
{:indent=>"  ",
 :space=>" ",
 :space_before=>"",
 :object_nl=>"\n",
 :array_nl=>"\n",
 :allow_nan=>false,
 :ascii_only=>false,
 :max_nesting=>100,
 :depth=>0,
 :buffer_initial_length=>1024}
```

You could try:

```
puts JSON.pretty_generate(object, array_nl: '')
{
  "a": {
    "b": 1
  },
  "c": [    2  ],
  "d": [  ],
  "e": {
  }
}
```

I know it's not exactly what you want, but using JSON.generate, you can customize JSON output generation only that much. There is no separate configuration for empty objects/arrays. Also, it's implemented in C, so monkey patching won't work as well.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's possible though the options, but here is a regex that achieves what you want.

```
structure = {
  "a" => {"b" => 1},
  "c" => [2],
  "d" => [],
  "e" => {}, 
  "f" => "string with [     ] and {       }"
}
json = JSON.pretty_generate(structure)

regex = /(?<content>"(?:[^\\"]|\\.)+")|(?<open>\{)\s+(?<close>\})|(?<open>\[)\s+(?<close>\])/m
puts json.gsub(regex, '\k<open>\k<content>\k<close>')
# {
#   "a": {
#     "b": 1
#   },
#   "c": [
#     2
#   ],
#   "d": [],
#   "e": {},
#   "f": "string with [     ] and {       }"
# }
#=> nil
```

The regex used starts matching from either a `"`, `[` or `{` character.

If it starts matching from `"` it will match till the end of the string, ignoring everything in-between. Capturing the whole string in the `content` group. The `open` and `close` groups will be empty. While substituting with `gsub` the whole `content` group will be placed back. This is done to negate `{` and `[` characters in string context.

If it starts matching from a `[` or `{` it only allows whitespace characters and looks for the matching `]` or `}`. The opening and closing characters will be placed in the `open` and `close` groups respectively, the whitespace in-between is not captured. The `content` group will be empty. Only the `open` and `close` groups will be placed back while substituting (removing the whitespace characters).

Here's a diagram of the match. It didn't like named groups, so I removed them to render the diagram. `group #1` correspond with `content`, `group #2` and `group #4` correspond with `open`, `group #3` and `group #5` correspond with `close`.

[image: regex diagram]

Comment: Indention can be changed through the `:indent` option. Supplying a string with four spaces increases indention from two to four spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Since Ruby's JSON formatting is limited, I generally use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to format JSON strings both in terminal and Ruby. When using jq with a pipe, the identity filter `'.'` is optional, but I like to keep it anyway.

```rb
require 'json'
require 'open3'

hash = {"a"=>{"b"=>1}, "c"=>[2], "d"=>[], "e"=>{}}
stdin_data = hash.to_json
formatted_json = Open3.capture2('jq .', stdin_data:)[0]
puts formatted_json
```

prints:

```json
{
  "a": {
    "b": 1
  },
  "c": [
    2
  ],
  "d": [],
  "e": {}
}
```

Comment: Note that this might fail if the JSON includes any `'` because they are used as the `echo` argument delimiters. Instead you could pass the standard input via `IO.popen` or `Open3.capture2`. eg. `require 'open3'` then `formatted_json, jq_status = Open3.capture2('jq .', stdin_data: json)`

Comment: Thanks, improved answer accordingly ✅